# How stream data to a PHP script using POST

Tags: php, file, streaming

So I am simply seeking to upload files to the server for later upload to Azure Blob Storage.
I am aware you can POST data using a HTML form, however this isn't a solution.
I would like to be able to upload files directly using POST such as through cURL or other means. As far as I'm aware PHP also requires the content type header to be specified as `multipart/form-data` for this.
I have tried to use file handles, but it appears that I am only able to interact with locally stored files. I have also played around with `move_uploaded_files`, but I am unable to POST files directly.
Streaming is important here, as files will likely be 5MB+, which wouldn't work for multiple concurrent uploads as PHP would quickly saturate its allocated memory; while I can change PHP settings on the staging server, I have no idea what the PHP memory allocation will be like on the Azure VM production server. It also wouldn't make sense to keep changing PHP settings with load increases.
However, if PHP does not offer such a solution out of the box, I'm open to alternatives.
To summarise, how do I stream data (e.g. videos) to a PHP file?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you streaming the video from a PHP website, or are you streaming it on your local computer and then wanting to upload it to a server (via hitting a PHP page)?

Comment: It will likely be neither, the current idea is to do it programmatically in Java and Python from other backend services we have.

Comment: I am not following why you need to use PHP then? Why not save it on the server with Java/Python if you are already streaming it in Java/Python? It seems like a whole extra hassle to POST it to PHP (not to mention how you will have to make the POST secure because people will try to send malicious POSTs to get reverse shells to your server).

Comment: Because the entire API was written in PHP by the previous dev team, and I'd like to keep this in PHP as well rather than having half the API in another, and half in the other.
Security isn't strictly an issue, we have authentication flows to ensure things work as intended.
Java/Python is used in end-user applications, the API isn't meant to be used directly, either.